# ¿Cómo hacer la asignación de valores a variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

Tengo que obtener un porcentaje en UNA VARIABLE en función a cantidades

```
DECLARE @COUNT_jURIDICOS AS INT, 
        @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_POR AS INT, 
        @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_PORCENTAJE AS FLOAT

SET @COUNT_jURIDICOS = (SELECT COUNT (*) 
                        FROM  [baseo].[dbo].[auxiliar2] 
                        WHERE [TIPO_PERSONA] = 'Juridico')

SET @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_POR = (SELECT COUNT (*) 
                                    FROM  [base].[dbo].[auxiliar2] 
                                    WHERE RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO > '0' 
                                    AND [TIPO_PERSONA] = 'Juridico')
```

Sabiendo las cantidades totales quiero sacar el porcentaje y ponerlo en una variable

```
SET @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_PORCENTAJE =  (@RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO / NULLIF ( @COUNT_jURIDICOS,0)*100)  

SELECT  @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_PORCENTAJE,  
        @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_POR, 
        @COUNT_jURIDICOS
```

El resultado de la división da 0
se que puedo unificar en un solo select pero los valores de las variables me sirven para otros procesos

| (No column name) | (No column name) | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7107 | 23049 |

Comment: Hola. ¿SQL server?

Comment: SI... SQL SERVER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás teniendo un problema debido a la funcionalidad de división de enteros. Al hacer divisiones entre enteros, el resultado será un entero y se elimina el residuo. Para obtener un valor fraccionario, debes de convertir los datos a un tipo de valor que lo permita como `decimal` o `float`.

```
SET @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_PORCENTAJE =  CAST( @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_POR AS float) 
                                        / NULLIF ( @COUNT_jURIDICOS,0)*100)
```

Como punto adicional, puedes obtener los dos valores iniciales haciendo una sola lectura de la tabla.

```
SELECT @COUNT_jURIDICOS = COUNT (*),
       @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_POR =  COUNT( CASE WHEN RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO > '0'  THEN 1 END)
FROM  [baseo].[dbo].[auxiliar2] 
WHERE [TIPO_PERSONA] = 'Juridico');
```

Inclusive, podrías obtener los 3 valores en una sola instrucción y si cambias el conteo por una sumatoria, puedes evitar la validación del cero (porque una sumatoria sin datos regresa nulo).

```
SELECT @COUNT_jURIDICOS = COUNT (*),
       @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_POR =  COUNT( CASE WHEN RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO > '0'  THEN 1 END),
       @RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO_PORCENTAJE = COUNT( CASE WHEN RAZON_SOCIAL_RESULTADO > '0'  THEN 1 END) / SUM(1.) * 100
FROM  [baseo].[dbo].[auxiliar2] 
WHERE [TIPO_PERSONA] = 'Juridico');
```